# Wifi connection on my new laptop

Tags: networking, password

I just got a new laptop and have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the same. Though its detecting my home wifi its not getting connected to it. Its asking for the password and when I provide the password it just comes back to the same window asking for password again. I have checked the password multiple times and its correct. Also at that time i was able to connect to my home wifi from my mobile and another laptop.

But when I switch on my mobile hot spot I was able to connect to it and and its working. Do I have to do something specific to get my laptop connected to my home wifi.

output of the command: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings in System Settings->Network->wireless need to match the settings in the wifi modem/router you are trying to connect to.

Check the "security" setting.  WPA2 is the latest and most secure but the device you are trying to connect to could be something older such as WEP.  This is set in the wifi security tab.

In the wifi tab, the mode needs to be set correctly.  For home wifi's this is usually "client".

You are probably trying to connect to an IPv4 device so in that tab you probably want to select DHCP.  Again, this all depends on how the home wifi device is configured.

A common mistake is typing the passphrase with cap lock on.  Also verify that all of the keys that control each character in your passphrase actually work every time.  In the wifi security tab you can click the "show password" button to verify that the passphase you entered is correct.

Most home wifi devices have a browser accessible administration capability.  You could connect the laptop that's working ok and monitor the logs on the home wifi while you are trying to connect your Ubuntu laptop.